# Pandas codification before comparison

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm using Pandas to look for a reference in a huge database. The problem is that I don't know the 'type' of this reference (string, int...).

```
Result = DataFrame.loc[(DataFrameComposants["Reference"] == str(Reference)]
```

I would like to convert the whole dataFrame into string because if the same reference has been stocked into an 'int' the comparison will be FALSE.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the type of a dataframe to string, you can use pandas [astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
reference_to_string = DataFrameComposants['Reference'].astype(str)
```

I am not entirely sure what you tried to do with your code...What is "Reference" in str(Reference) ?